# Rendering data from other websites

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do i render or extract data of other websites not having api into my website?
Using **javascript and react** preferred

I want to show data of multiple websites in my website, but the websites don't have their APIs so how can i read the data of the websites

Comment: if they don't provide an API, then you may want to do some reasearch about "web scraping"

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using iframe:

```
<iframe src="urlOfPageYouWantToRender" title="description"></iframe>
```